# Consuming user profile properties in Master Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I would like to show the users first name on all pages if they are logged in.

I am using VS2013.3 and WebForms.

So far I have added additional properties including first name to the user profile when they register.

I would like to use the new profile information in in the site master page (site.master).  The boilerplate template uses

```
<%:Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()%>
```

I can access the first name property of the user using

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
user.FirstName;
```

I am fairly new to C# and ASP.net

How do I reference my new user profile property though in the site.master.aspx page?  Do I need to do in a load event or similar or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I don't know if you've a solution but I will post my idea which i got from your question and another [article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/securing-asp.net-mvc-applications-with-asp.net-identity.htm) cos I was also having the same problem. I added firstname and lastname to ApplicationUser in identitymodel then used this code in site.master.cs

public static string GetFirstName()

```
    {
        string firstname;

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

        firstname = user.FirstName;                              


        return firstname;
    }
```

And I use it on the master page with this
<%: GetFirstName() %>
Hope it helps